# Reason for Precision and Recall terminology?

Tags: terminology, precision-recall

Why are the statistical indicators Precision and Recall named that way? Is there a canonical interpretation?

Comment: Interesting question. **Precision** being: Positive Predicted value, TP/P∗, Precision, (1−false discovery proportion) and **Recall** being: True Positive rate, TP/P, 1−Type II error, power, sensitivity, recall. From ISLR, 7th ed, table 4.7

Comment: "Sensitivity" made always sense to me, "recall" never. Maybe because I come froma medical background but a good explanation why Recision and Recall are named that way would help me a lot remembering, which was which. Great question!

Answer (score 0):

Precision is the number of **true positives** divided by the number of **predicted positives**. It means how accurately your predicted positives are. The emphasis lies in your predicted positives being precise.

Recall is the number of **true positives** divided by the number of total **actual positives**. It shows how much actual positives you can capture. The emphasis lies in capturing or finding the complete set of the actual positives.